# MongoDB: Trade-offs of dropping a collection vs. removing all of its documents

Tags: mongodb

What are the trade-offs of dropping a MongoDB collection vs. removing all of its documents (assuming the collection will be re-created immediately)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you go through a remove all the documents from a collection, then you'll be doing a lot more work (freeing the document's storage, clearing the index entries that point to the document, and so on). If you instead just drop the collection, it'll just be reclaiming the extents that the collection and its indexes use.

One other difference is that dropping the collection will also remove the collection's indexes.

Answer (score 31):

A benefit of simply dropping a collection is that it is much faster than removing all of a collection's documents.  If your collection will be "re-created immediately" anyway (assuming that includes index re-creation), then this is probably the most-attractive option.

The authors of the book [MongoDB: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381561) (Kristina Chodorow and Michael Dirolf) ran an experiment where they provided a Python script which timed a `drop` vs. a `remove` of 1000000 records.  The results came in at 0.01 seconds for the `drop` and 46.08 seconds for the `remove`.  Now while the exact times may differ based-on hardware and other factors, it nonetheless illustrates the point that the `drop` is significantly faster.

reference: 
Chodorow K., Dirolf M. (2010). “MongoDB: The Definitive Guide.” O'Reilly Media, Inc. Sebastapol, CA., pp.25

Comment: +1 on the answer, but one caveat with drop vs remove, and that is when you are in a sharded environment, there have been several bugs over the various versions related to reusing a dropped collection name (or even a prefix in certain cases).  The latest relevant bug that I know of is this one: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4262 and it is fixed in 2.2 - just something to be aware of if you are planning a lot of drops/recreates.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @AdamC!  I suppose this scenario does get a little tricky with sharding/replication in the mix.  I have a master/slave replication config in my lab at home that I'll have to try that on.

Answer (score 2):

Removing and Dropping a collection is mostly implementation detail.

**Removing** a collection requires an **one by one update of internal state** that happen to exists in the collection.

**Dropping** a collection requires  **freeing up some large data structures** inside the database of data files.

Dropping collection is vastly faster than removing one by one until collection is empty.

**Meta data** like indexes will **exists if the collection is removed** rather than when its dropped.

Source: MongDB University course

Answer (score 0):

Once we have documents stored in our collection , we can remove all of the documents from it in two ways. Now choosing one over another is totally depends on your requirement.

**1. [Using drop():](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.drop/)**
By invoking `drop()` on a collection , it will remove all the documents from it ,it will delete all the indexes on it  and at the end it will delete the collection itself.

**2.[Using remove():](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)** 
 remove has two overloaded versions ,one in which we will pass the criteria to remove all the documents that are matching our passed criteria and 2nd one is default where we won’t pass any criteria (prior to 2.6) or pass an empty document (version 2.6 or more) and it will remove all the documents from the collection. Here, we are more interested in 2nd version when our intention is to clear all the documents from a collection.

**Remark:** *To remove all documents from a collection, it may be more efficient to use the `drop()` method to drop the entire collection, including the indexes, and then recreate the collection and rebuild the indexes.*